# Middleware in NodeJs always redirecting to the same page (I guess)

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm developing a page in order to learn in NodeJs with express and ejs.
In a routes file if match to `/` or `/login` checks if logged in. If not, loads the login page, otherwise loads the admin page. This work fine, I added another routes to redirect to some other pages. To check if logged in I use a middleware `requireLoggedIn`, here is my code:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get(/^\/$|^\/login$/,function(req,res){
        if(req.session.loggedIn == undefined)
        {
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.render('pages/login');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("here")
            res.writeHead(301, {
                Location: '/admin'
            });
            res.end();
        }
    }).listen(3000);

    function requireLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.session || req.session.loggedIn === undefined) {
            res.writeHead(301, { 'Location': '/login' });
            res.end();
            return;
        }
        next();
    }

    app.get('/admin', requireLoggedIn, function(req,res){
        res.send('HERE WILL BE ADMIN PAGE');
    });

    app.get('/new-product', requireLoggedIn, function(req,res){
        res.render('pages/new-product');
    });
}
```

After logging in, if I want to go to `/new-product` it's always redirecting to `/admin`. I thought it was a problem on my regex on the first route (Because is the only place that redirects to `/admin`), but I added a console.log, and is not logging when trying to load `/new-product` and loads `/admin`.
Removing the middleware the pages loads just fine, so I guess the problem is there, but I don't see which is the problem

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

After clearing browser cache, I can load correctly, to any page, but after the first load of any page, all other pages will redirect to that.

**EDIT**

I add more code with more debugs, to check:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get(/^\/$|^\/login$/,function(req,res){
        console.log(req.session.loggedIn);
        if(req.session.loggedIn == undefined)
        {
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.render('pages/login');
            console.log("NOT LOGGED IN");
        }
        else
        {
            req.session.loggedIn = true;
            console.log("REDIRECT TO DASHBOARD")
            res.writeHead(301, {
                Location: '/dashboard'
            });
            res.end();
        }
    }).listen(3000);

    function requireLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.session || req.session.loggedIn === undefined) {
            res.writeHead(301, { 'Location': '/login' });
            res.end();
            return;
        }
        next();
    }

    app.get("/dashboard", requireLoggedIn, function(req,res){
        console.log('LOAD DASHBOARD');
        res.render('pages/dashboard');
    });

    app.get("/new-product", requireLoggedIn, function(req,res){
        console.log('LOAD NEW PRODUCT');
        res.render('pages/new-product');
    });
}
```

(`/admin` now is called dashboard, but is the same).
**Step by Step**

1. Clear browser cache and start node
2. `localhost:3000/` --> get logged `NOT LOGGED IN`
3. Login and automatically redirects to `/dashboard` --> get logged  REDIRECT TO DASHBOARD`| Then get logged -->`LOAD DASHBOARD`
4. `Try to enter in /new-product` --> get logged `LOAD DASHBOARD`

Comment: How do you know if you are logged in ? I don't see you setting `req.session` or `req.session.loggedIn` anywhere

Comment: In other file when I post to login from the view `req.session.loggedIn = true;`
Anyway if I print on the middleware, the session is set

Comment: console.log( JSON.stringify( req.session, null, 4 ) ); in the first line of your requireLoggedIn might help u track the issue, because all behaves like req.session isnt what u expect it to be. Also, I never saw a .listen(3000) at that place in a node code, but that might have nothing to do with it ^^

Comment: @Radioreve I have tried, but the session has what I'm expecting, It redirects to the `/login` and 'here' is not logged neither, so the redirect problem is not happening there

Comment: Sorry bro just, i'm not sure I follow. You say "after loggin in", so based on that, the problem occurs when you expect your req.session object to be populated right ? That's why I suggest you log it.

Comment: The user login, and redirect to `/admin` correctly. Then I try to load `/new-product` and I'm being redirected to `/admin`. However the `here` is not logged, so It's not on the first route.
I'm neither redirected to login, so the session has the correct content.

If I delete browser cache, and re-login, and go to `new-product` it works, but if I want to go back to `/admin` it redirects back to `/new-product`

Comment: what happen if you remove the middleware?

Comment: The pages return 404 (of course), but the redirect is not done. That's why I think the problem is there

Comment: What do you mean 404 (of course)? without the middleware the `/admin` route should display `HERE WILL BE ADMIN PAGE`

Comment: Sorry, i misunderestand.. yes, it works fine.. but wont check for login

Comment: Even, if I check inside every route for the session it still working fine.. but I want to avoid repeating code

Comment: Looks like a session or "loggedIn" variable checking issue.
Maybe "req.session.loggedIn" is null or false or true?
Add more debug logs or show us more code.

Comment: I added more code with example

Comment: Something seems wrong with the way u do things Pablo. You know, everytime you redirect, I think the req.session object gets reseted. So setting req.session.loggedIn = true before a redirect doesn't work. You have to use a mechanism to keep track of he session, either based on cookie or token (sent by the browser), and probably use a server side storage mechanism to persist those informations ( like redis to be sure these persists even when u reboot ur app)

Comment: Try to replace `req.session.loggedIn === undefined` by `!req.session.loggedIn`

Comment: Are you using a proxy server like nginx or apache? It could be some permanent redirect configured at that level

Comment: I have tried in other computers, and seems that the problem is in my browser. in other browsers it work just fine.

Comment: Try switching to 302 redirect...

301 redirects are often cached

Comment: @Gary That was it!! Thanks!!

Comment: @Pablo Can you mark answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching to 302 redirect... 301 redirects are often cached.

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding extra parameter to you middleware - usually called next.

Basically:

```
next() without parameter invokes the next route handler in framework.
```

Then:

```
if(req.session.loggedIn == undefined)
        {
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.render('pages/login');
            console.log("NOT LOGGED IN");
        }
        else
        {
            next();
        }
```